# How to assign the undo command to the Ctrl-z key binding?

Tags: key-bindings, undo

I have added:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)
```

to my `~/.emacs` file. But still when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> nothing is undone even when I've had GNU Emacs open for a while and done several things in my present buffer. You can even see in my Edit menu that Undo isn't set to my desired key binding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/a2e42e46dd0109ff8a6ec20f07b5b3622cd978bb/.emacs) is my `~/.emacs` file, if relevant.

Comment: The edit menu doesn't show you every key sequence. What does `C-h C-k C-z` tell you?

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/0kAcL8e.png)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should have asked what does `C-h k C-z` tell you? Anyhow you have your solution, so no need to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that it seems to be related to me still having a `(cua-mode t)` line in my `~/.emacs` file. After I removed this line, the line:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)
```

in my `~/.emacs` file worked just fine.