# How to bind org-agenda-undo to C-z when cua-mode is enabled?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-agenda, undo

By default, `C-_` runs the command `undo` (found in `global-map`). It also runs `org-agenda-undo` when in Agenda view.

As I use `cua-mode`, I undo changes with `C-z`. My issue is that it doesn't work in Agenda View. I tried to bind `org-agenda-undo` with `C-z` :

```lisp
(define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "C-z") 'org-agenda-undo)
```

or

```lisp
(use-package org-agenda
  :ensure nil
  :bind
  ("C-z" . org-agenda-undo))
```

But it didn't work. How can I do it without altering `cua-mode` behavior?

Comment: I put the two blocks in my init and restarted emacs twice to test each alternatively. In my init, `cua-mode` is enabled first. I confirm that by default `C-z` doesn't work on Agenda View when `cua-mode` is enabled (I did a test with an init only containing `(cua-mode t)`). Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign the undo command to the Ctrl-z key binding?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29174/how-to-assign-the-undo-command-to-the-ctrl-z-key-binding)

Comment: @Drew, I don't want to remove `(cua-mode t)`. I mean I would like to keep using `cua-mode`.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/37277/.

Comment: Also, I wonder why `cua-mode` isn't adapted to Agenda views...

Comment: @Drew, I'm not sure to understand the second solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associate all the commands triggered by `C-_` with `C-z`:

```el
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-z") (kbd "C-_"))
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT

As you mention in the comments, the original answer defines the new keybinding globally. To set the keybdinging only in the org-agenda buffer you could use

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'cua-base
  (defvar cua--org-agenda-keymap (copy-keymap cua--cua-keys-keymap))
  (define-key cua--org-agenda-keymap (kbd "C-z") #'org-agenda-undo))

(defun cua--org-agenda-override-keymap ()
  (setq-local cua--keymap-alist (copy-tree cua--keymap-alist))
  (setf (alist-get 'cua--ena-cua-keys-keymap cua--keymap-alist) cua--org-agenda-keymap))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook #'cua--org-agenda-override-keymap)
```

END EDIT

From using `C-h k` `C-z` from within the org-agenda buffer, you can find that the cua-mode `C-z` binding is found in the `cua--cua-keys-keymap`. So, to define the new binding for it, just use that map (after activating cua-mode)

`(define-key cua--cua-keys-keymap (kbd "C-z") 'org-agenda-undo)`

Comment: With your solution, `C-z` is bound to `org-agenda-undo` in Agenda Views indeed. But the issue is that outside of Agenda Views it is also bound to `org-agenda-undo` and no longer to `undo`. So your solution is altering `cua-mode` behavior outside of Agenda Views.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. I have updated the answer...

Comment: Yes, I would need other `cua-mode` bindings in Agenda Views, like `C-c` (`cua-copy-handler`) for example.

Comment: That binding still works, see `M-x describe-keymap` `cua--cua-keys-keymap` for the commands that will be disabled. It seems to me that those bindings are not required in org-agenda.

Comment: With your solution, `C-c`, to copy selected text from Agenda Views, no longer works.

Comment: You're right, although I checked the code, somehow I did not do it correctly. Well, I have updated the answer again with (indeed a non-trivial) solution. But now I see that you have found a much more elegant solution already...

Comment: Thank you @dalanicolai, I gave an upvote to your answer already. However, I think I'll accept mine (when available) as it is simpler.

Comment: Yeah, for sure, your answer should be the accepted answer :)